# Can't scroll over userControl added into a panel

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, panel

I've faced a problem at my new development: WinForms Desktop app.

I've created a new userControl which has a height of 2000, and I want to add it to a panel that has a height of 1200. To achieve this I've set `userControl1` `AutoScroll = true`

But when I run my application the scrollbar doesn't appear and y can scroll over the `userControl1`:

[image]

This will be the desired behaviour:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
  VisorIncidenciaControl tr = new VisorIncidenciaControl();
  tr.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
  panel1.AutoScroll = true;
  panel1.Controls.Add(tr);
```

Comment: It's the Panel that should AutoScroll.

Comment: Hi @Jimi thanks for your reply. Unfortunately your answer for me doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what *doesn't work* means.

Comment: The scrollBar doesn't appear. @Jimi

Comment: If your UserControl and your panel are the same width, you likely just placed the UserControl _over_ the panel. To test it out, make your control a bit smaller, width-wise (which will also prevent the horizontal scrollbar from appearing). The suggestion by @Jimi is the correct solution.

Comment: If your UserControl is docked to fill, no scroll bars. Of course, the UC must be child of the Panel.

Comment: The scrollbar must be shown automatically, but it doesn't appear. The behaviour is the one which is shown in the first image, I can see the bottom of my userControl without a scrollBar. I've added the code to the question.

Comment: Remove the `tr.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;` line

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem of the scrollBar, now it appears but it does't fill the content horizontally.

Comment: You'll need to set the width manually. You can set the `Size` property on the UserControl to be about 25 pixels less than the width of the panel, and whatever height you need.

Comment: Set the `[UC].Size = [UC].PreferredSize`, if the UC's content overflows its ClientRectangle bounds. It will adapt to the content. You can also try the AutoSize property (it may behave differetly in some situations).